# ReaderWriterLock blocks when trying to read resource

Tags: .net-core, task-parallel-library, readerwriterlock

I am trying to use a `ReaderWriterLock` for a shared resource between two `Tasks`.For some reason it starts waiting indefinitely:

```
class State {

        private const int TIMEOUT = 5000;
        private ReaderWriterLock lck = new ReaderWriterLock();
        private TimeSpan lastIssuedAt;

        public TimeSpan LastIssuedAt {
            get {

                this.lck.AcquireReaderLock(TIMEOUT);
                return this.lastIssuedAt;
            }
            set {
                this.lck.AcquireWriterLock(TIMEOUT);
                this.lastIssuedAt = value;
            }
        }
}
```

When a task tries to `get` the property `LastIssuedAt` it just blocks and I do not understand why.

Comment: You have to release the lock as well.

Comment: I thought that it gets released when the method exits.Also do i need to release the `Readerlock` too ?Also for the `get` where do i release it ? before `return` ?

Comment: Do i need an additional variable for the `get`? `get {  lock.AcquireReader(); var value=... ; lock.ReleaseReader(); return val ; }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the example on MSDN: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.readerwriterlock?view=netframework-4.8

You forgot to release the lock. A common pattern for doing so is try/finally:

```
ReaderWriterLock lck = new ReaderWriterLock();

lck.AcquireReaderLock(timeOut);
try
{
    // Do what needs to be done under the lock
}
finally 
{
    // Ensure that the lock is released.
    lck.ReleaseReaderLock();
}
```

Also, check out ReaderWriterLockSlim: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.readerwriterlockslim?view=netframework-4.8
Which MSDN recommends for new development.

Comment: But in my case i need to release the lock in the `getter`.

Comment: That's the magic of 'finally'. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/try-finally Anything in the finally block will run when you leave the 'try' block. So you're lock will get released even if you return out of 'try'.

Comment: I didn't want to use a `try-catch` inside the `getter`.

Comment: You don't need a catch. Just try/finally